# How can I show a TGA image in a <img> tga?

Tags: html, tga

I have a TGA image encoded in Base64

https://gist.github.com/984770

But it doesn't show on the browser.

Is there a way to show a TGA image on the browser or it is not supported? Is there any client side technology I could use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [not supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

I assume there probably are Java or ActiveX plugins that can do it, but it's going to be complicated, cumbersome, have spotty support, and of course won't work with base64 data.

If it's just a few images, consider converting them to JPG, PNG or GIF manually, depending on what type of image they contain.

If it's many images and you need an automated solution, a good way  would be to employ a server-side script that calls e.g. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), and creates a JPG thumbnail from the image.

You could easily send the base64 data to the script using Ajax for example, receive the name of the converted file in return, and create an `<img>` element pointing to it.